# Opening another powershell terminal from the current script to execute the current script output

Tags: windows, powershell

```
    $argList = "-file `"C:\Users\bdl\Desktop\jhansi\PowerShell_Scripts\dialog.ps1`""
Start powershell -argumentlist $argList -NoNewWindow
```

I am trying to open another powershell terminal from the current script to execute the current script output. Another powershell terminal is opening but it is blinking continuously. The above two lines of code i have written but it is blinking. please tell me where is the mistake in the above two lines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sir actually i want to open another powershell terminal from the script to execute the script output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$ArgList = "C:\Users\bdl\Desktop\jhansi\PowerShell_Scripts\dialog.ps1"
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList $ArgList -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

You can also check if the script called in PowerShell returns successfully or not by adding an exit code into it (Exit 0 means it succeed and Exit 1 if it fails) with:

```
$Exe = (Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList $ArgList -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode

If ($Exe -ne 0)
{
    Write-Host "An error has occured while running the script."
}
```

As the exit code other than 0 means the script didn't finish properly.

Comment: Sir i have added as you said above terminal is opening but script is not running.